# Find file and rename it automaticly with php coding

Tags: php, rename

I have a directory of images, and it has morethan 800 images, i want to replace their names some logic...

Logic is; Find files and replace them from "cool" to "hot" words in their names in the specific directory.

My directory : /images

I want to replace these words: "cool" with "hot" words.

Old: images/this-is-cool-weather.jpg

New: images/this-is-hot-weather.jpg

How can i do that with PHP ?

Comment: Have you tried something? Or did some research ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would take 5 minutes for you to make that if you did some research

```
<?php
foreach (glob("images/*.jpg") as $filename) 
{
  $newname=str_replace("cool","hot",$filename);
  rename($filename, $newname);  //add some error checking here, dont assume.
}
?>
```

Provided you have appropriate permissions :)

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

Here I only grab files which contains the word "cool" with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). After this I go through all files and [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) the file and [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) "cool" to "hot"

```
<?php

    $files = glob("images/*cool*.jpg");

    foreach($files as $file)
        rename($file, dirname($file) . "/" . str_replace("cool", "hot", basename($file)));

?>
```

Comment: That's a `cool` touch :)

Comment: Great , you're code is working too.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to implement something like

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    rename($filename, str_replace('cool','hot', $filename));
}
?>
```

Please note, this has no exception handling and or other pointers.
This should get you started

Comment: Great , you're code is working too.